# How to display JSON informations in a ListView (django rest-framework)

Tags: android, json, django-rest-framework

I want to display JSON informations in an android app's ListView.
I'm using Django Rest Framework , i already serialized my objects and converted the info to JSON format and are accessible via 127.0.0.1:8000/.
Here are my objects :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have to use [retrofit library](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) with [gson library](https://github.com/google/gson).

Gson: serialization/deserialization library to convert Java Objects into JSON and back

Retrofit: Retrofit turns your HTTP API into a Java interface.

Once you get a hold of the list of object in java you can use a adapter in a list view to display the objects. [tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: I want to display data from url